# Can SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor be removed from the code if we create the bean manually and inject it?

Tags: spring, autowired, interceptor, ejb-3.0, applicationcontext

I am trying to upgrade spring from 4 to 5 in one of our project due to security reasons. In one class, we are using SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor as an interceptor. I went through the documentation, where they have mentioned it is used to inject bean which are annotated with @Autowired. So, if it is used for autowiring, can I remove the said interceptor altogether and inject the bean with @Inject annotation (of course after creating the required beans). Is there any difference between directly injecting the bean and Interceptor injecting it for you?

Original Code snipped:

```
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)

public class foo(){

@Autowired
SomeBean bean;
}
```

I have removed the interceptor and changed the code to:

```
public class foo(){

@Inject
SomeBean bean;
}
```

I did some sanity around these flows and they are working perfectly fine with these changes. So not sure if it will impact in any other way.

Comment: The `SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor` is only needed if you are using this to inject Spring dependencies into EJB managed beans. If you aren't using EJB3 to manage these beans there is no need to use the interceptor (or to use `@Inject` for that matter).

Comment: So, what is the difference between Interceptor injecting the spring beans vs we doing it manually via @Inject. Sorry if the answer is something obvious.

Comment: YOu aren't injecting anything manually.